# Rotate multiple images in Javascript

Tags: angularjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I have background image on background of canvas. And i want to put another image on background image. SO i can rotate upward image in any direction. I am trying javascript code which is available on internet. But both images were rotated. I want to rotate only upward image with some angle.

```
/* Upload first image to 0,0 co-ordinate. */

ctx.beginPath();
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() 
{
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 300, 150);
};
imageObj.src = 'C://Users//rajesh.r//Downloads//images//images.jpg';
options.ctx.fill();
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.translate(400,300);
  ctx.rotate(2*Math.PI / 8);
  var thumbImageObj = new Image();
  thumbImageObj.onload = function() 
  {
    ctx.drawImage(thumbImageObj, 0, 0, 120, 20);
  };

  thumbImageObj.src = 'C://Users//rajesh.r//Downloads//images//images.png';
  ctx.fill();
```

I want some solution so i can rotate second image by some angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `rotate` on your canvas, you're not rotating an individual image, but instead rotating the entire canvas. To only rotate the second image you need take advantage of the `save` and `restore` methods provided by the canvas API.

Here's an example, based off of the code that you shared:

```js
// canvas setup
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// 1st image
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 100, 100);
};
imageObj.src = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/so-answers/image1.jpg';

// 2nd image
var thumbImageObj = new Image();
thumbImageObj.onload = function() {
    // save current canvas state
    ctx.save();
    // perform transformation
    ctx.translate(110,110);
    ctx.rotate(20*Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.drawImage(thumbImageObj, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    // restore original canvas state (without rotation etc)
    ctx.restore(); 
};
thumbImageObj.src = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/so-answers/image2.jpg';
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```